# Reading big .csv file MATLAB with commas

Tags: matlab, csv, readfile, bigdata

I have a big csv file (6.5millions x 25) and trying to load it to Matlab. I already tried `xlsread` , `csvread` but can't get satisfying results. I read I can achieve it by using `textscan`.

My data looks this way:

```
date_time;writetime;F1;F2;F3;R1;h12;b12;h_main;
01.01.2016 0:00:01;504910801075;1;1;1;3,94;799;1515;3,877;
01.01.2016 0:00:02;504910802314;1;1;1;3,96;795;1516;3,857;
```

First row is a header. Others rows are data. All other rows are of the same format.

My code:

```
fileID = fopen('value1.csv','r');
formatSpec = '%s; \n';

formatSpec1 = '%s%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n';
A1 = fscanf(fileID, formatSpec);

A2 = textscan(fileID, formatSpec1,'Delimiter',{';', ','});
```

I read header to `A1` it's ok:

```
A1 =
date_time;writetime;F1;F2;F3;R1;h12;b12;h_main;
```

And read data to `A2` too.

```
A2 = 
    {1x1 cell}   [5.0491e+11]   [1]   [1]   [1]   [3]   [94]   [799]   [1515]   [3]   [877]
```

**But how to read `3,94` values?** Because it can be just `4` or `0,064` value in this column.

Hope at your help!

Comment: do those numbers always have a decimal delimter? like 4,00

Comment: Your fields are separated with `;` so don't use comma `,` as a field separator.

Comment: @Finn no, it can be just `4`.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki you are right! I already changed it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat them as a string. The following works.

```
fileID = fopen('value1.csv','r');
formatSpec = '%s; \n';
A1 = fscanf(fileID, formatSpec);
formatSpec1 = '%s%f %f %f %f %s %f %f %s\n';
A2 = textscan(fileID, formatSpec1,'Delimiter',{';'});
A2{6} = str2double(strrep(A2{6},',','.'));
A2{end} = str2double(strrep(A2{end},',','.'));

{1x1 cell}    [5.0491e+11]    [1]    [1]    [1]    [3.94]    [799]    [1515]    [3.8770]
```

Comment: I went the same way! Didn't heard about `strrep` before, thank you!

Comment: I have one refinement for your solution: we can't use `strrep( char(A2{12}), ',','.');
Error using strrep
Input strings must have one row. `
But we can go `str2double( strrep( A2{12}, ',','.') );`

Comment: ? the size of A2 array is 9, right? Also, A2{end} is a string, right?

Comment: Oh, I failed with the indexes - in my question I showed simplified example, in my real data it is much larger. I meant `A2{6}` of course. `strrep` wants to get one row, but `char(A2{6})` is a column.

Comment: I see. `strrep` works on cells as well. Changed!